# Dynamically center 2 lines of text programmatically with roughly equal length per row

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

My situation is that I have a line of text that can vary in length due to localization. This will need to be displayed on the screen such that each line is roughly of equal length, and is centered.

**This is my very long line.**

Should look like this

```
  This is my
very long line.
```

Comment: If it's two UILabels, this is very simple. (1) Set the text alignment to center. (2) Set the UILabel's centerXanchor equal to the superview's centerXanchor. (This may also work for a multi-line UILabel.)

Comment: @dfd This won't work since it is a localized string, so it must be one label as the length can vary greatly.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - and if so, please explain and I'll delete. One language is as good as another, and the answer explains multi-line. So all that (I see) is left is to center the UILabel. Since labels have intrinsic width, you can set a Y coordinate (or use centerYanchor) and using centerXanchor... what am I missing?

Comment: @dfd We are localizing for 15 languages, including Chinese, Japanese and Korean which can be much shorter than something like German. Any how, I figured it out once I took the size of the label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I took a crack at this and got something that works the way I want it now.

I take a localized string, set it to an empty label, and find out what it's size is. (The orange is just for illustrative purposes)

With the size of the label, I then divide it by 1.8 which gives me some buffer room to account for inconsistent word sizes (again, I don't know what will be here in advance). Finally, I multiply the height by 2.0, and set that as my new frame. Finally, I add it to the view.

This has held up with a few sample strings, though it would need to be revised to handle more than 2 lines (currently, not an issue).

```
let text = NSLocalizedString("This is my very long line of text.", comment: "")
let instructionLabel = UILabel()
instructionLabel.text = text
instructionLabel.textAlignment = .center
instructionLabel.backgroundColor = .orange
instructionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
let size = instructionLabel.intrinsicContentSize
let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width / 1.8, height: size.height * 2.0)
let rect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)
instructionLabel.frame = rect
view.addSubview(instructionLabel)
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

And an even longer one:

[image]

Just for some variety, this is the second string above, but in Arabic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this to set alignment.

```
myLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Also set the number of lines to 0. And if you want a specific width, set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property like so:

```
myLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 80
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

Comment: As per my comment (made as you were giving this answer), don't forget to center the UILabel. The easiest is using centerXanchor, but you could also set the leading/trailing anchors.

Comment: @aziz I tested this approach as well to see if it was cleaner than what I went with, but even using the preferredMaxLayoutWidth, I was still getting a a longer row on the top than the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work for arbitrary localizations (assuming languages that use spaces), you would need an algorithm that split the text on spaces and then loop through each combination of top and bottom text, measuring its width, to see what gave the most evenly distributed sizing. This feels like overkill.

Having done a fair amount of localization, the better bet is to manually insert `\n` characters in the .strings file to adjust breaks that aren't visually pleasing.  Relying on a fixed width will work for many languages, but won't give you the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: We frown upon using \n in our localization as it is not allowed by our translator & creates a lot of problems if we change the UX since we now have to update all our strings.

Comment: I certainly understand @CodeBender.  There always seems to be a trade off between code portability and typography.  Your idea of taking the total width and multiplying by a factor certainly works, until someone has copy with a few very long words in a row that causes strange wrapping.

Comment: True, right now I am relying on them telling me that there is a requirement it take no more than 2 rows on any device. However, if I need 3+ rows, I would rely on the intrinsic size width, and to then calculate how many rows I need by dividing that against a value (screen width, view width, etc.) and using that to determine my height.